# How to include the full property name using a custom htmlhelper from within an editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, html-helper, mvc-editor-templates

I have a registration form into which I am trying to place an Html.EditorFor().

EG:

```
@ModelType RegisterViewModel 
    <othermarkup />
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.ConfirmPassword, New With {.class = "required"})
    <div>
        @Html.PasswordFor(Function(m) m.ConfirmPassword)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.AlertSettings)
</div>
<othermarkup />
```

The RegisterViewModel contains a property called AlertSettings (of type AlertSettingsViewModel) and the Editor Template for AlertSettingsViewModel.vbhtml looks something like this:

```
@ModelType AlertSettingsViewModel
    <othermarkup />
<div class="panel-heading">Personalized Alert Settings</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div>
            <label for="Disciplines">Disciplines</label>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Disciplines)
            @Html.CheckBoxListFor(Function(m) m.Disciplines, SelectLists.Disciplines())
        </div>

        <div class="visible-xs"><br /></div>
    </div>
</div>
<othermarkup />
```

The Disciplines property of AlertSettingsViewModel is an Integer array.

I'm using a custom HtmlHelper to generate the Checkbox List.  This is comprised of the two following methods (first calls the second):

```
''' <summary>
''' Returns a checkbox for each of the provided <paramref name="items"/>.
''' </summary>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function CheckBoxListFor(Of TModel, TValue)(htmlHelper As HtmlHelper(Of TModel), expression As Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TValue)), items As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem), Optional htmlAttributes As Object = Nothing) As MvcHtmlString
    Dim listName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)
    Dim metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData)

    items = GetCheckboxListWithDefaultValues(metaData.Model, items)
    Return htmlHelper.CheckBoxList(listName, items, htmlAttributes)
End Function




''' <summary>
''' Returns a checkbox for each of the provided <paramref name="items"/>.
''' </summary>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function CheckBoxList(htmlHelper As HtmlHelper, listName As String, items As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem), Optional htmlAttributes As Object = Nothing) As MvcHtmlString
    Dim Result As String = ""
    For Each item In items
        Dim div = New TagBuilder("div")
        div.MergeAttributes(New RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), True)
        div.MergeAttribute("class", "checkbox") ' default class

        Dim label = New TagBuilder("label")

        Dim cb = New TagBuilder("input")
        cb.MergeAttribute("type", "checkbox")
        cb.MergeAttribute("name", listName)
        cb.MergeAttribute("value", If(item.Value, item.Text))
        If item.Selected Then
            cb.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked")
        End If

        label.InnerHtml = cb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) & item.Text

        div.InnerHtml = label.ToString()

        Result &= div.ToString()
    Next

    Return New MvcHtmlString(Result)
End Function
```

The problem I am having is that when the editor template is called, the eventual call to ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression) returns only the immediate property name (eg. "Disciplines") instead of the full name in context (eg. "AlertSettings.Disciplines").

How can I get the full name instead of just the immediate name?  This is my first attempt at using editor templates and I'm having some difficulty finding examples for this particular use case.

Comment: Start by renaming you `EditorTemplate` to `AlertSettingsViewModel.cshtml` (not `_AlertSettings`) and then in the view its just `@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.AlertSettings)`

Comment: And you extension method should be making use of the built in html helper methods so your get full model binding rather than manually constructing your tags.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  I tried using the built in helper, but it generates a hidden field of the same name for each checkbox.  So if I have 50 items in my list, then 50 hidden fields post 50 false's.  Additionally, if I select an item, then I get an error trying to convert the checkbox value to a boolean.

Comment: Thats because you not using an `EditorTemplate` correctly. It should be named the same as the model and located in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder and called using `@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.AlertSettings)`

Comment: I forgot to mention in my previous comment that I went ahead and made the necessary changes to follow the conventions you mentioned (I've updated the question also).  The issue of the hidden fields presented by using the `htmlHelper.Checkbox(listname)` persisted regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to rectify the issue by replacing:

```
Dim listName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)
```

with:

```
Dim listName = htmlHelper.NameFor(expression).ToString
```

In the CheckboxListFor method.

Hopefully this will be of some use to someone else.

Comment: `htmlHelper.IdFor(expression)` might also be useful in this scenario